# Tavern(pytest), disable SSL Certificate Validation

Tags: python, testing, ssl-certificate, pytest

I'm attempting to test Tavern in our test environment. Of course, there is an invalid SSL Certificate in the test environment and this is preventing Tavern from completing a test.

The error message reads:

> SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='url-to-host' port=443): Max
>   retires exceed with url: /folders/in/url (Caused by
>   SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate
>   verify failed (_ssl.c:726)'))

Is there a way to disable SSL Certificate Validation in Tavern so I can continue in our test environment?

Comment: additionally, I found this in the documentation, but no example was provided:

https://taverntesting.github.io/documentation#running-against-an-unverified-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just had the same issue.  You can add

```
verify: false
```

to your request yaml.

Comment: Thank you. That fixed my issue.